# how to find the intersection of two Writeablebitmap using c#

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I have two black and white pictures in `writeablebitmap` . and I want to find the intersection between them to check if the pictures have some similar area. Their size is same.

I am trying to do something like this and I am sure that am missing something or doing something wrong because I am not getting the result that I want.

```
int[] p1 = pic1.Pixels;
int[] p2 = pic2.Pixels;
int len1 = p1.Length;
int intersection=0;
 for (int k = 0; k < len; k++)
 {
      if (p[k] == p1[k])
            {
                intersection++;
            }
  }
```

Am I going all wrong or this code can somehow work?

Comment: I think you have a typo? Shouldn't it be `if (p1[k]==p2[k]) {...}`

Comment: my bad but I don't have this error in real code

Comment: Well for starters you're not taking the width and height of the images into consideration.  Not an issue if you know they will both have the same width and height.

Comment: @juharr height and width is same I just didn't add that code here

Comment: @Saira In that case this should give you the count of pixels that the images have in common based on location.  Not sure if that's what you mean by intersection though.

Comment: @juharr even the count will work for me but its not giving anything.

Comment: @Saira You mean you're comparing two images that have the same colors in the same areas, but `intersection` is zero?  Also I assume that it should be `if(p2[k] == p1[k])`.  My suggestion is to step through the code and look at the pixel values.  If the color at corresponding pixels is off by the slightest bit then it will not match.  That is a color of say (10, 50, 50) will not match (9, 51, 51) even though both would "look" the same to the human eye.